# Why does my routing number (IBAN) come up as invalid

Tags: united-states, banking, international-transfer

I am trying to wire funds and my routing number to Citibank, which is 122401710 in Las Vegas Nevada, is coming up invalid IBAN when I go to wire funds.

When I called Citibank they told me that I think by mistake, but it was an international routing number.

I said it wasn’t.  If you look it up online that Routing number is in fact for Nevada, but it’s also registered in Delaware blah blah blah.

Anyway Citibank could not even give me an answer or let me know how to wire funds.  Can anybody tell me exactly what the heck is going on? I would also like to know exactly where my bank account is located.

It’s actually my trust. When I called Citibank, the girl said she couldn’t even locate my trust fund with the account number I gave her.

It’s just getting weirder and weirder. I want to know if my account is actually in United States. And where in the heck is it? Someone please tell me what’s going on. I’m actually very concerned no one can give me answers. They give me answers; they just contradict each other.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Exchange! It sounds like you're trying to deposit money into your Citibank trust fund; is that right? Are you the trustee, the beneficiary, both, or neither? Did you open the trust fund yourself or did someone else? When was the trust opened?

Comment: Did you call the general Citibank 800-number, or contact Citibank **Trust Services**?

Answer (score 6):

IBAN is an european concept (some others have adopted IBAN aswell) and american accounts dont have IBANs yet (https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/International_Bank_Account_Number).

The IBAN starts with a two letter country code - this tells you where the account is located (e.g. DE for Germany or GB for the UK).

For US transfers you should just need to give the ABA code (bank code) with account number.

Comment: `e.g. DE for Germany`  **NOT** DElaware!

Answer (score 0):

Technically, US bank accounts have two components:FRD (4 digits) and ABA(4 digits +check digit) followed by your bank account number (variable number of digits). All the components are required to designate an account within a bank within a Fed district.